# load MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database

Tags: python, dataset

what is the best file format to use and how can I load the database correctly and plot sgnals in python.

I am using a .dat file from https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mitdb/

I used these code

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = np.genfromtxt('100.dat',delimiter=',')
print(data)
```

and I got this error :

```
*line 1867, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #3 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #6 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #9 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #11 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #12 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #16 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #17 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #18 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #20 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #23 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #27 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #36 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #37 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #66 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #67 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #100 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #105 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #106 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #118 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #120 (got 5 columns instead of 1)
Line #122 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #123 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #125 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #126 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #127 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #128 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #134 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #135 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #137 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #141 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #143 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #146 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #147 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #148 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #149 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #152 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #154 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #156 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #162 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #163 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #167 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #168 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #174 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #175 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #176 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #177 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #179 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #186 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #187 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #188 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #189 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #191 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #193 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #196 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #199 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #202 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #203 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #204 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #209 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #210 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #211 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #213 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #218 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #222 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #223 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #228 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #236 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #240 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #241 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #244 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #246 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #255 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #257 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #268 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #269 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #271 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #273 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #280 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #281 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #291 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #323 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #325 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #334 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #340 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #341 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #342 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #364 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #372 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
Line #375 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #378 (got 6 columns instead of 1)*
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [wfdb-python](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python) package. The documentation is really pretty good, and there are plenty of examples. To install it in your environment, you can simply do `pip install wfdb`.

Assuming you have the data files (including the `100.dat` file you mentioned above) in a local directory called `./mitdb`, you can read a record with the following:

```
import wfdb
record = wfdb.rdsamp('mitdb/100', sampto=3000)
annotation = wfdb.rdann('sampledata/100', 'atr', sampto=3000)
```

You can then plot the data using the following function:

```
wfdb.plotrec(record, annotation = annotation,
         title='Record 100 from MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database',
         timeunits = 'seconds', figsize = (10,4), ecggrids = 'all')
```

If you don't already have the data files locally, you can use `wfdb` to download them:

```
import os
wfdb.dldatabase('mitdb', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'mitdb'))
```

This will download the records and save them in a local directory called `mitdb`

Comment: can  I use the same code to plot data from one file ? if so what modifications should be done ?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about individual files since `wfdb` uses the abstraction of records. As a user, you don't need to know anything about the layout of individual files on disk. 

However, if you just want to plot a single signal from a particular record, that should be possible. I'm not entirely sure but I think you want to look at the `channels` keyword argument of `rdsamp`.

Comment: okay I'll try that otherwise is there a way to plot the signal from a .dat file as I have a single .dat file containing the signal and I don't get how to plot it

Comment: Why can't you use the instructions I provided for using `wfdb` to download the database entry you need? This is how the database is intended to be used, instead of processing individual files, regardless of whether you're using the Python library or not. You asked how to load the database correctly, and how to plot the data, and I believe I answered both of those questions.

Comment: I just tried this solution and it works perfectly well even with a directory containing a single file , I suppose this piece of information might be usefull and so it's worth sharing

Comment: I think I may have mentioned that it works with local data files in my answer ;), but I can update it to clarify.

Comment: Just a small correction: to download the data files locally, we should run: `wfdb.dl_database('mitdb', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'mitdb'))`

Comment: @RenatoCandido good catch! I fixed it in the example now :)